# How can I display my code input alongside code output like I see on stackoverflow answers?

Tags: python

I am currently learning to program with Python, and I've been making notes in a text editor as I read books, etc. Is there an easy way to create "code snippets" similar to the ones I see in stackoverflow answers like this:

[image]

What I like is that I can see the output from the code in a different color, directly beneath the input. I intend to take these code snippets and throw them in a pdf (or online with http://hilite.me/) for future reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open your [python](/questions/tagged/python) interpreter by typing `python` into your [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) shell:

```
bash-3.2$ python
Python 2.7.5 (default, Mar  9 2014, 22:15:05) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 5.0 (clang-500.0.68)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> mylist = [x*x for x in range(3)]
>>> for i in mylist:
...     print i
... 
0
1
4
>>> exit()
bash-3.2$
```

Comment: Maybe add the options for Windows as well?

Comment: Yes, I have been using my bash shell in my coursework, but I guess I miss the keyword colors that my text editor creates. I see that when you replied to my question, you may have just copied/pasted the text from your shell. Where did the colors come from?

Comment: @reddhouse stackoverflow automatically syntax colors for us :)

Comment: It turns out if I just copy/paste the output from my shell into hilite.me, that it will produce the desired (color coded) effect. Just needed to put 2 and 2 together. Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

One nice tool that you can use is [IPython Notebook](http://ipython.org/notebook.html). With that you can combine code execution, rich text, mathematics, plots and rich media as said in IPython website.

What it all means? You can have a fancy way to store and share your snippets. You can use rich text to explain your snippets. More than that, you can run your snippet and watch it dynamically, observing what it does in fact.

Take a look in the [introductory video](https://youtu.be/H6dLGQw9yFQ), also from IPython website.

IPython Notebook is part of IPython package which you can install with `pip`. For more information or other ways to get it, take a look at [IPython documentation](http://ipython.org/ipython-doc/stable/install/index.html).

Comment: :) Great answer +1 for typing the same answer at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

Python on the command line is great as user1823 pointed out.  Since you mentioned saving your snippets to pdf I would suggest you look at [IPython Notebook](http://ipython.org/notebook.html).  It is just like running from the command line, but it runs in your web browser.

You type some code into a cell, run it, save the code and output. When you exit, the notebook saves the state of your work (as a .ipynb file) so you can pick up where you left off.  You can also export it as a pdf.

You can include LaTeX and other markup in your notebook.  You can share it with others and they can pick up where ever you last saved.

On my mac I launch Ipython Notebook from [Anaconda](http://continuum.io/downloads), which is a Python distribution that comes bundled with many popular packages (SciPy, Numpy, BeautifulSoup, 300 others).

Comment: Well...I was grabbing the Anaconda link lol